# Query for similar array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'd like to search for documents with similar arrays in my MongoDB collection and order by similarity value.

**Example**:

I would search for `{chars:['a', 'b', 'c']}`

And I have stored those documents:

```
1. {chars:['s', 'e', 'c']}
2. {chars:['i', 'l', 'd']}
3. {chars:['b', 'a', 'c']}
4. {chars:['f', 'c', 'b']}
```

I'd like to get something ORDERED like:

```
[
  {chars:['b', 'a', 'c'], similarity: 1.0},
  {chars:['f', 'c', 'b'], similarity: 0.66},
    ...
]
```

Which operator or query strategy should I use to get something like that?

*Thanks!*

Comment: The only way I see is to use a reduce map function and do things by hand

Comment: @asierguti This can not be done with $text operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all that tried to help me. I appreciate your help.

I have found a solution via aggregation pipeline.

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$chars',
    },
    {
        $match: { chars: { $in: myArray } },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            count: 1,
            score: { $divide: ['$count', myArray.length] },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: { score: -1 },
    },
]);
```

This is what console gives back:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586ebeacb2ec9fc7fef5ce31"), "count" : 3, "score" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586ebeb9b2ec9fc7fef5ce32"), "count" : 2, "score" : 0.6666666666666666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586ebe89b2ec9fc7fef5ce2f"), "count" : 1, "score" : 0.3333333333333333 }
```

Hope somebody finds this usefull.